# Select rows were some column is equal to the max value for a group of matching rows in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(A = c(5, 5, 6, 6, 5), B = c(5, 5, 9, 9, 5), C = c(4, 1, 9, 1, 1))

A  B  C
5  5  4
5  5  1
6  9  9
6  9  1
5  5  1
```

If rows in the data frame have the same number in column B, then I only want to keep the row that has highest value in column C.

So according my condition, I am expected to get the filtered data frame like:

```
A  B  C
5  5  4
6  9  9
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>% 
  filter(C == max(C))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   A, B [2]
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     5     5     4
2     6     9     9
```

Answer (score 4):

With R base `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(C~A+B, data=df, max)
  A B C
1 5 5 4
2 6 9 9
```